# PHP OOP: retrieve data from database

Tags: php, oop

I'm pretty new to OOP (and also in PHP programming), and I have some troubles using objects and interfacing them with db data (MySql in my case, but this is irrelevant).

I have on the DB a table `USERS`. I declared a `class User` in the PHP code, with the various properties and methods I need. The problem is interfacing this thing to db. 
I put code to retrieve data from the db in the constructor, so when I need to work on a specific user, I simply write `$user = new User($user_id);` and start working with the object. 
When I've done I call a method on the object to save data on db, and this works pretty well.

The problem arise when I need data about **many users in a single page**, as in showing the complete list of users. With this approach, when I need the list of users, I have to instantiate all the objects, and this causes the code to make **too many queries** of the type `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ...`, instead than a single query such as `SELECT Only_needed_fields FROM users WHERE 1 LIMIT 20` as I would've done in procedural code.

Which is the correct OOP approach to such a problem? Which is the good-practise alternative to retrieving data in the constructor?

**Notice** Please, don't suggest using frameworks of any kind - I'd like learn pure OOP PHP before using abstraction layers -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not seperating the layers of your application. What you should do is have a factory class instantiating your users that handles the database calls and let the user class only handle the business logic. This will also contribute to the testability of your code.

Your factory class could have two methods. One for loading a single user and instantiating it and another for loading a set of users.

Comment: Well said.  Also, I'd say using a singleton object structure for your DB is the way to go.

Comment: Hm, so when I need a user, I call something like `Factory::GetUserById($id)` or `Factory::GetAllUsers()` etc..., and let the User constructor do not initialize parameters? 
Seems a good idea, I didn't think of it, thanks a lot.
(it seems quite difficult to abandon procedural paradigms :-))

Comment: Thanks. I would disagree on the singleton pattern though as it makes your code harder to test. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI You would rather want to pass every dependency using a constructor or method than altering the global state.

Comment: marcello: Yes, your user constructor instead just accepts the parameters that make up the actual user instead of having to take the burden of getting it's own data. You will have the added benefit of being able to mock-up other structures should you want to test your code with phpUnit for example.

Comment: @afullyllama why singleton? sorry but I don't unserstand... I don't have to be sure having only one object instantiated, it is not simpler to just declare static methods? (perhaps singleton could be useful for the database wrapper class, but this is another story)

Comment: marcello: I think he was refering to the database wrapper.

Comment: @Dan True, and I'll have also the benefit of straightforward code to make a new user, and so on.
Only a doubt: using the factory class, should I put the code to save edits to data to db somehow in the factory class, or it's ok leaving it in the User class? (now I have a property `$toUpdate` that gets put to TRUE by every methods that changes properties, and a `$user->commit()` method to update db if `$toUpdate == TRUE`. Before the end of object scope, I call the $user->commit() - the idea, sooner or later, is to put commit() in the destructor -)

Comment: I would seperate the whole database communication and move it to the factory class. If you think such an update function is necessary you could pass the factory instance to the user when creating it and let the __destruct method issue the database change using the corresponding method of the factory class. that way you have the database change is one class the the logic in the other. Also when testing you can create a mocked-up factory class and still test the logic in your user class.

Comment: mmh, yes, thanks. I think the update function is necessary, unless there are better ways to trigger saving object's properties changes to db.

Comment: Is there a way to contact you outside of SO? Lengthy dicussions are discouraged but I don't mind giving further advice.

Answer (score 2):

A factory method is always plausible, then you can implement an optimised common query:

```
list($one, $two) = User::GetMultiple (array( 1, 2 ));
```

Translating into

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN ( 1, 2 );
```